# How to exclude a column from ORDER BY in SQL?

Tags: sql

I don't know if my query in possible or not. But, I want to Order By all columns DESC except one Column to leave it as it is. For example I have a table as follows

```
 Name   ID   DateOfEntry
 Alex   12    12/03/2019
 John   11    11/03/2019
 Jessie 13    13/09/2019
```

What I want to do is that I want to order by DESC the ID but I want the DateOfEntry to be excluded as follows

```
 Name   ID   DateOfEntry
 Jessie 13    12/03/2019
 Alex   12    11/03/2019
 John   11    13/09/2019
```

How can I do this ? Is it possible to have a new column "DateOfEntry_new" that takes the DateOfEntry as under some condition with in the example will be ORDERBY ASC to be the output as follows

```
 Name   ID   DateOfEntry  DateOfEntry_new
 Jessie 13    13/03/2019  12/03/2019
 Alex   12    12/03/2019  11/03/2019
 John   11    11/09/2019  13/03/2019
```

Comment: `ORDER BY ID DESC` will only take ID into consideration.

Comment: This is not ordering though. What you are asking is actually modifying the contents of the table. I think you need to redesign your database if you see yourself needing to do this. Maybe you can give us more information about what you are trying to do and we can help you better.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you want to change the date for each name?